# Separate even and odd index of strings and print them respectively - Problem with last char print

Tags: string, printf, stdin

I know there is 2 other discussion on this topic but I can't find the response to my single problem.
When I print the last character of my even (or odd) index string, I looks like weird ones. I think it is because I miss something with fgets and with "s[j] [ (strlen(s[j])) -1 ] = '\0'". I don't feel comfortable with strings and user input management. Can you help me please ? Many Thanks !

```
int main() {
/* Declaration of int variables*/
    int d = 0;
    int nbEven = -1;
    int nbOdd = -1;

/* User inputs management */  
    scanf("%d",&d);
    fgetc(stdin);

/* Char matrix declaration based on user inputs */ 
    char s[d][1000];
    char evenChar[d][1000];
    char oddChar[d][1000];

/*Write into user matrix */
    for (int j=0; j<d; j++)
    {
        fgets(s[j],sizeof s[j],stdin);
        s[j] [ (strlen(s[j])) - 1 ] = '\0';
    }

/*Even and odd index processing */
    for (int j=0; j<d; j++)
    {   nbEven=-1;
        nbOdd=-1;
        for(int i=0 ; i<strlen(s[j]); i++)
        {
            if (i%2 == 0)
            {   nbEven++;
                evenChar[j][nbEven] = *(s[j]+i);
            }
            else{
                nbOdd++;
                oddChar[j][nbOdd] = *(s[j]+i);
            }
        }
        /*I DON'T KNOW IF I SHOULD DO THAT OR NOT...*/
        //evenChar[j] [ (strlen(evenChar[j])) ] = '\0';
        //oddChar[j] [ (strlen(oddChar[j])) ] = '\0';
    }

  final print of results*/
   for (int k=0; k<d; k++)
    {
        printf("%s %s\n",evenChar[k], oddChar[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I say "weird" character printed is those ones : ��X>��N

Comment: You have unbalanced comment delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>         /*I DON'T KNOW IF I SHOULD DO THAT OR NOT...*/
>         //evenChar[j] [ (strlen(evenChar[j])) ] = '\0';
>         //oddChar[j] [ (strlen(oddChar[j])) ] = '\0';
> ```

Since the arrays are uninitialized, if you want the contents to constitute strings (which have to be terminated by a null character) you definitely should do something like that, but not exactly that, because `strlen` is of no use before actually strings are formed. What you should do is:

```
        evenChar[j] [ nbEven+1 ] = '\0';
        oddChar[j] [ nbOdd+1 ] = '\0';
```